# ¿Cómo añadir o configurar una firma en la cabecera de una clase en Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

estoy trabajando con Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 en proyectos de C++, y quería saber cómo puedo hacer para configurar esa cabecera de comentarios que suele aparecer que indica nombre de autor, fecha, copyright, etc.

Actualmente al crear clases, no me aparece nada, directamente ya el pragma once...

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Saludos.

Comment: Podria servirte http://abhijitjana.net/2010/12/05/add-document-header-for-files-automatically-in-visual-studio/

Comment: No se trata de ningún duplicado, de hecho son temas completamente distintos, Tuttini. 

Por otro lado, Intentaré hacer lo que me has indicado, jasilva, gracias.

Comment: @ChemaEgea Nos comentas si te ha servido :)

Answer (score 3):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear un [Snippet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-co/library/ms165394.aspx) en Visual Studio con la información que requieres que sea insertada en como firma (Me refiero a autor, fecha, etc.)

Según tengo entendido sólo se puede hacer manualmente ingresando los comentarios que necesites por lo que no sería automaticamente al crear una clase como lo solicitas pero es algo. Por ejemplo escribiendo un comando xx para que ingrese la firma que requieras.

Ejemplo de un Snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title></Title>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Code Language="">
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

No sé si hablas inglés pero aquí hay una [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199409/inserting-copyright-notice-banner-in-all-source-code-files-in-visual-studio-2012) de Stack Overflow en inglés que te puede servir.

Personalmente no lo he probado pero parece que es la mejor opción.

Otra solución posible es por medio de un programa que añada la firma como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
List<string> files = new List<string>()
{
    "c:\\Form1.cs",
    "c:\\Form2.cs",
};

foreach (string file in files)
{
    string tempFile = Path.GetFullPath(file) + ".tmp";

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(tempFile))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(@"// <copyright file=" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) + @" company=My Company Name>
// Copyright (c) 2012 All Rights Reserved
// </copyright>
// <author>Leniel Macaferi</author>
// <date> " + DateTime.Now + @"</date>
// <summary>Class representing a Sample entity</summary>
");

            string line = string.Empty;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
    File.Delete(file);
    File.Move(tempFile, file);
}
```

Hay otras aproximaciones que podrían funcionar entre las cuales están crear una macro o configurar un template como se describe en este [post](http://abhijitjana.net/2010/12/05/add-document-header-for-files-automatically-in-visual-studio/) como lo sugirió ***jasilva*** en el comentario a tu pregunta, pero me parece que no funciona muy bien en Visual Studio 2015.

Espero que esta respuesta te sirva.